# Is it safe to have "relational database?"

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I just want to know if it's safe to have two databases that are relational to one another, rather then the tables inside the database being relational to one another? (don't get me wrong the tables will still be relational)

Comment: Explain what you mean by two databases in more detail.  Different databases on the same computer?  Different vendors (MySQL and SQL Server/Oracle/PostgreSQL/etc)?

Comment: You keep using that word. I do not think that word means what you think it means.

Comment: I think you mean having foreign keys between tables. A table *is* a relation (roughly speaking); it isn't "relational" to other tables.

Comment: Well you're not going to get any referential integrity, but other than that I don't see any problem.

Comment: @Marcelo: I can see it now, the Bill Clinton of tables sitting in court saying, "I did not have relations with that table."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual relations are usually enforced by the application that is using the database. So if you have a relation that goes from database A to database B, then you can just implement it like that in your application.

Of course by having two different databases, you can't get the internal support for relations you usually get from the database system. So for example you can't specify foreign keys and add rules based on them.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it but it's probably not a good idea. To keep relational integrity between a table in one database and tables in another you would need to use some sort of distributed transaction which covers both databases. This is far more complicated than a transaction spanning a single DB.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "safe." If your tables are InnoDB, you can do transactions across databases in the same server. Foreign key constraints apparently [also work.](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,150829,200251#msg-200251)

Enforcing either of these across more than one server is, I believe, not possible.